# drools and getting text by xpath

Tags: java, xpath, drools

This is part of my xml:

```
<abstract>
  <p>x</p>
  <p>y</p>
  <p>z</p>
  <p>w</p>
</abstract>
```

currenly I'm using this this xpath in my drool `/record/metadata/document-export/documents/document/abstract`.

The problem is that I'm getting empty string, because I think it is taking the text between `<abstract>` and `<p>` - empty string.
How can I take all the text inside the abstract by xpath:

```
<p>x</p>
  <p>y</p>
  <p>z</p>
  <p>w</p>
```